# Inserting username into table - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple auction website. I need to keep track of the user that adds items to the auction. I've figured out how to store the user's account id and I thought storing the username would be similar, but I am unable to work it out. No matter what I've tried, the username is never stored in my items table.

This is my additemprocess.php page.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
require_once("dbconnect.inc");

$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
$item=$_POST['item'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$accountid=$_SESSION['accountid'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO biditems (username, accountid, biditem, biddesc) VALUES
('{$_SESSION['username']}', '$accountid', '$item', '$description')";

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in adding item: " .mysql_error());
$mess="Item successfully added!";

echo $mess;
?>
```

And here is the page that should list the items, showing the username of the user that added the item.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbconnect.inc");
require_once("checkstatus.inc");

$sql=" select * from biditems";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "Items for Auction";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$itemid=$row['itemid'];
$item=$row['biditem'];
$auctionby=$row['username'];
$description=$row['biddesc'];
echo "<p>$itemid $item $auctionby $description</p>";
}
?>
```

Here is my code to add an item.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbconnect.inc");
?>
<form id="additem" name="additem" method="post" action="additemprocess.php">
Item<br>
<input type="text" name="item" id="item"/><br>
Description<br>
<textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Make sure [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) isn't one of the users.

Comment: As @Shomz mentioned, you may want to look at SQL injection at some point. What error are you getting?

Comment: Does your form have a `<input name="username" />`? Have you tried printing/echoing `$_SESSION['username']`? Does your query fail, and you get an error message from `mysql_error()`?

Comment: @asifrc I wasn't getting an error at all. The item would be added with everything else except for the username.

Comment: @lulu, try `echo $sql;` before the `$result=mysql_query($sql) or ...` line in additemprocess.php. Does the sql statement have your username?

Comment: What is stored in the `$_SESSION['username'];`?

Comment: @Peurr see OP's line 8 - `$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];`

Comment: @asifrc, It does not.

Comment: @LuluSparks then back to what @Sean was asking, do you have an input with `name="username"` on the page that's submitting to additemprocess.php?

Comment: show your form that is posting to `additemprocess.php`. My guess is either you don't have a `<input name="username" />`, so `$_POST['username']` is empty, or you have an error in your code of adding the username to value of `<input name="username" value="**USERNAME**" />`

Comment: @LuluSparks same place you put the `echo $sql`, try `print_r($_POST)`.. does that contain the username?

Comment: You added your login form (as it goes to `verifylogin.php`). We need the form that you use to send to `additemprocess.php`

Comment: You're not escaping strings before storing in DB, sure there's no problematic character in the username value?

Comment: Also, try to `echo` the $_SESSION['username'], since I think that's where your problem is. Check my answer underneath, should work.

Comment: the session_start comes too late in your form... (but it seems you're not using the session variable, so this shan't be the problem)

Comment: @fpierrat he's starting the sessions on top of the page, so that should be good.

Comment: @peurr: the html section has been edited since my comment... 
lulu spark: you should make explicit edits.

Comment: So in the form you just added, you don't have a `<input name="username" value="**USERNAME**" />`. So where is the `username` to magically appear from for `$_POST['username']`? `$_POST` will only contain key/values that you define in your form. It would magically transfer from your login form to your add item form just because you hope it will.

Comment: @Sean that's coming from the `$_SESSION['username']`, which is probably set somewhere in the process of logging in. But I think something is going wrong with that.

Comment: I started learning PHP a few weeks ago so sorry. Thank you for your help so far, @Sean. How could I get the username without making the user enter it again?

Comment: Do you save the username to `$_SESSION['username']` on successful login, as you do with `$_SESSION['accountid']`? If so, then remove the `$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];` line, and just let it populate using the default `$_SESSION['username']` value. If not, you could either add it to your form OR you could get ti using `$_SESSION['accountid']` and a `INSERT ... SELECT` query.

Comment: @LuluSparks Check my solution down here, should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using `$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];` but you need to treat this username like the accountid. It should have been stored when you login in a session, then recalled when you enter the bid data in its database.

So for example:

On login :

```
$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
```

And on storing the bid:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

or alternatively get the username from the users table using the accountid then add it to the query that way like:

```
$username = $row['username'];
```

Additionally, if you tried this but had trouble sharing this data between pages using sessions, then make sure you are including `session_start();` on the top of each page where you are going to use sessions.

Comment: I don't see the point. When the form gets posted, the value ($_POST['username']) is stored in the DB in additemprocess.php. 
Then when he needs it again, he reads it from the DB (select query). There's no need of session variable to do that.

Comment: @fpierrat There's nothing linking to the `$_POST['username'];`.

Comment: @peurr yes I noticed you edited your answer after i answered. You realise we can see what time you edited your answer right ? I created mine 8 minutes ago, you edited and added your solution 6 minutes ago.

Comment: @n099y you can see that I just edited parts of the answer. As you can see agian, I added some new information.. But well.. who cares. Let's not fight lel..

Comment: @peurr: i was sure i had seen an <input name="username' /> somewhere... but it must have been in sean's comments above.

Comment: @fpierrat, there was a username on his login form he had posted. but that was not directed at the php in question. This was the root cause, I assume I was on the right track seeing as he accepted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is at: `$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];`, you're setting a `session` to a `post` which doesn't even exist..? Set the `$_SESSION['username']`; in the process of logging in.

So on the spot where you are setting the `$_SESSION['accountid']` equal to the `ID` of the currently logged in account using something like: `$_SESSION['accountid'] = $row['id']`;.

Right under there you'll add `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];`.

Then just delete the `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` at your adding item process.

---

**ANOTHER NOTICE:** Do not use MySQL anymore since it's deprecated in versions of PHP5 or higher due safety reasons. Try using MySQLi (MySQL improved or PDO): php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: not the DV, but be aware of (1) you are missing the column in `... accounts.userID=auctions` (2) the `mysql` extension is `deprecated` not `departed`, and (3) never link to w3schools, when you should be linking to the actual php docs - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: @Sean ah, well thanks.. sorry for referring to w3schools.